# wxpython , passing boolean flag for background checking

Tags: python, wxpython, controls

How can i get a value from button click from my frame?

```
btnYes = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK")     
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickYes, btnYes)

def clickYes(self, evt):
       print "clicked Yes"
       self.Close()
```

whenever a user click yes , i want to get a value to check in other module. Something like confirmation flag. When user is confirmed one item then carrying on doing other items. The confirmation flag i will be using is here below :

```
def my_methodABC():    
    matchList = []
    for x, y in product(d1rows, d2rows):
        if userConfirmedFromWxPythonClickYesButton():
           matchList.append(abc)

    return matchList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a MessageDialog. There are lots of examples on the web. Here are a couple:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/MessageBoxes
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/

And here's a really simple example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Ask Question")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.showMessageDlg)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def showMessageDlg(self, event):
        """
        Show a message
        """
        msg = "Do you want to continue?"
        title = "Question!"
        style =  wx.YES_NO|wx.YES_DEFAULT|wx.ICON_QUESTION
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, message=msg, 
                               caption=title, style=style)
        result = dlg.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_YES:
            print "User pressed yes!"
        else:
            print "User pressed no!"
        dlg.Destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You would probably want to call your match list method if the user pressed the yes button rather than just printing a message to stdout though.

Comment: dear @Mike Driscoll thank for the answer, i would like to know whether can i pass the "result" outside of this class? Because , as my question stated, i would like to check while it is looping in another class.

Comment: GUIs are event based. If you have a long running process, it will block the GUI and it will freeze and be unusable. You will have to put your loop into a thread and use wx's thread-safe methods to pass messages about. Or if this is a loop that is run when the user presses a button and the loop itself is displaying the messagebox, I think that would work. However, this in this latter case, the result would be returned to the loop itself, so there is no "passing" it to another class.